# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST in Laravel livewire

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-livewire

Sorry, I have a routes problem in laravel livewire. I want to test my login form validation on my website by continuously clicking the submit button (after giving a response of course), and on the fifth (5) click I have a problem "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST". Does anyone know about this problem? Because I also tried it on a simple form on localhost and there was no error.

I use laravel livewire 2.2

This is the code on my website,

Blade

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="check">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label">Email</label>
      <div class="input-group">
         <input wire:model.defer="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="xxx@xxx.xx">
         <div class="input-group-append">
            <span class="input-group-text">
            <i class="mdi mdi-check-circle-outline"></i>
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
      @error('email')<label class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</label> @enderror
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label">Password</label>
      <div class="input-group">
         <input wire:model.defer="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="**********">
         <div class="input-group-append">
            <span class="input-group-text">
            <i class="mdi mdi-check-circle-outline"></i>
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
      @error('password')<label class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</label> @enderror
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-success submit-btn btn-block" wire:loading.attr="disabled" >
         <div wire:loading.remove>Login</div>
         <div wire:loading>
            <div class="loading-bar bg-white"></div>
            <div class="loading-bar bg-white"></div>
            <div class="loading-bar bg-white"></div>
            <div class="loading-bar bg-white"></div>
         </div>
      </button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Controller

```
class Login extends Component
{
    
    public $password;
    public $email;

    protected $rules = [
            'password' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
        ];
        
    public function check()
    {
    
        $this->validate($this->rules);

        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $this->email, 'password' => $this->password]))
        {
            
            redirect()->to('livewire/add');
            
        }else
        {   
            
            $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('alert', ['type' => 'error', 'title' => 'Error','message' => 'Credential not valid']);

        }
        
    }
    
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.login')->extends('backend.v2.master');
    }
    
}
```

Routes

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'livewire'], function() {
       Route::get('/login',Login::class);
       Route::get('/add',Add::class);
});
```

First submit

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADqHh.png)

Error result after the fifth click

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzLUP.png)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: remove `method="post"` from `<form>`

Comment: Sorry, I added the "method: post" code when I tried to solve the problem, I forgot to delete it when I posted on stackoverflow. I tried it without or using the code "method: post" has no effect, I still have that problem. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping the whole form in a div element?

```
<div> 
{{-- Anything you want to do --}}
</div>
```